# jQuery - Redirect webpage after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I want to redirect my page to another one if I stay there for a  certain time. I tried to write the following script and I put it in the head of my webpage but it doesn't work. The location where to move isn't a real url because I'm on XAMPP.

```
$(document).ready(setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.replace("../index.php");
}, 5000););
```

Comment: Even if you are on XAMPP, how can that not be a real URL?

Comment: how can I obtain my url using javascript?

Comment: Using `location.href`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you have given is totally wrong, causes a Syntax Error. Check your console. The `ready()` function expects a function and not an integer (as returned by `setTimeout()`).

Try this way:

```
$(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.replace("../index.php");
  }, 5000);
});
```

Or if you want to use only after 5 seconds of inactivity, you need to use a different approach by checking the user activity (`keypress`, `mousemove`) and then clear the timer and restart it.

If you wanna try the redirect after 5 seconds of inactivity, you can do this:

```
var timer = 0;
function startRedirect() {
  timer = setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.replace("../index.php");
  }, 5000);
}
function restartTimer() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  startRedirect();
}
$(function () {
  startRedirect();
  $(document).mousemove(restartTimer).keyup(restartTimer);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without JS by putting right meta tag into your header

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url=http://google.com">
</head>
```

where "5" is wait timeout.

Comment: *`I want to redirect my page to another one if I stay there for a certain time.`* - This definitely uses some conditions. Yours will automatically redirect after 5 seconds. Doesn't that sound wrong?

Comment: yes, right, you need JS to handle condition state here.